# Generate edge-based outline

Tags: inkscape

Given a basic black-and-white outline drawing, such as:

[image]

I'd like to convert it from a PNG with a black outline to an SVG with only black paths.

I know it's possible to detect edges in an image. Is it possible to convert these edges into SVG paths using Inkscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: trace bitmap]

The above image is a screen capture of the Trace Bitmap feature found under the Path menu. The stroke is set to (thin)black, fill to none.